# Java | Get constructor reflectively

Tags: java, reflection, constructor

How I can get constructor reflectively, if its param is `Object ... objects`.

My constructor:

```
  public MyClass ( Object ... objects )
  {
    if ( ! ( objects == null ) )
    {
      if ( objects.length > 0 && objects [ 0 ] instanceof Long )
      {
        setLatency ( ( Long ) objects [ 0 ] ) ;
      }
    }
  }
```

How I get it now:

```
Class< ? > clazz = Class.forName ( "MyClass" ) ;

Constructor< ? > clazzConstructor = clazz.getConstructor ( Object [ ].class ) ;
```

What I try to do:

```
Long latency = 1000L ;

MyClass myInstance = ( MyClass ) clazzConstructor.newInstance ( latency ) ;
```

And I get
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

If latency == null, everything works.

Comment: How about `newInstance(new Object[]{latency})`?

Comment: I tried, but it still don't work.

Comment: @Banthar It would work but for the fact that `newInstance()` itself is varargs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your constructor is expecting an object array but you're passing a single `Long` to it.

Wrapping `latency` into an object array will work, although be careful as `newInstance()` itself is expecting `Object ...`, and if you pass it nothing but an `Object[]`, it will interpret it as a list of arguments. So you'll have to do something like this:

```
MyClass myInstance = ( MyClass ) clazzConstructor.newInstance ( (Object)new Object[] { latency } ) ;
```

or

```
MyClass myInstance = ( MyClass ) clazzConstructor.newInstance ( new Object[] { new Object[] { latency } } ) ;
```

The first one "fools" the compiler into wrapping your object array into another, the second one does it explicitly instead.

(Passing null only worked because null is null, no matter what the declared type of the parameter is.)

Comment: Isn't a Long an Object though?

Comment: @skynorth Where it says `Constructor< ? > clazzConstructor = clazz.getConstructor ( Object[].class ) ;`

Comment: @Shakesbeer I tried both solutions and they worked. How does it fail for you?

Answer (score 7):

Try it this way

```
MyClass myInstance = (MyClass) clazzConstructor
        .newInstance(new Object[] { new Object[] { latency } });
```

`newInstance(Object ... initargs)` needs array of objects as arguments. Buy your fist argument in constructor is also array of object `Object... o` so you need to wrap it again in Object array.

I tested it with this code and in seems to work fine

```
class MyClass {
    private Long latency;

    public void setLatency(Long latency) {
        this.latency = latency;
    }
    public Long getLatency() {
        return latency;
    }

    public MyClass(Object... objects) {
        if (!(objects == null)) {
            if (objects.length > 0 && objects[0] instanceof Long) {
                setLatency((Long) objects[0]);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class<?> clazz = MyClass.class;

        Constructor<?> clazzConstructor = clazz.getConstructor(Object[].class);
        System.out.println(clazzConstructor);

        Long latency = 1000L ;
        MyClass myInstance = (MyClass) clazzConstructor
                .newInstance(new Object[] { new Object[] { latency } });
        System.out.println(myInstance);
        System.out.println(myInstance.getLatency());
    }
}
```